# How to trigger a function of sibling component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to front end world and could not figure out how to trigger a function from a sibling component. Lets say I have 2 component in App.js. The page is:
[image]

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Customer List</h1>
      <MainPanel/>
      <TableFooterPanel/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MainPanel code is:

```
function MainPanel() {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostList = async () => {
      const response = await service.getCustomerList();
      setCustomers(response.data);
      console.log(response.data)
    };
    fetchPostList()
  }, []);

  const deleteCustomer = (id) => {
    service.deleteCustomerById(id);
  }

  return (
    <ReactBootStrap.Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {customers &&
            customers.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.firstName}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td><Button onClick={() => deleteCustomer(item.id)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashRestore} /></Button></td>
              </tr>   
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </ReactBootStrap.Table>
  );
}

export default MainPanel;
```

And TableFooterPanel code is:

```
function TableFooterPanel() {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const addNewCustomer = (name, surname) => {
        service.addCustomer(name, surname);

    }

    return (

        <>
            <Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <Button onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

What I want to do is, whenever I click button and send the customer info to backend to save then immediately call a function in MainPanel to set it's table data and update the table immediately after adding. Something like, I want to click button and add it and if response is success then refresh the table (without refreshing whole page).

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React we have one data flow. From parent to children, and there is no way to pass some information, from children to parent/sibling. What you want is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up)

Just put necessary logic to parent component, here it will be the `App` component. In App component you will have a function which triggers table data loading, and when data will be loaded you should save it, also inside the `App` component. You will pass table data to MainPanel as prop. Then pass a that function from App component (which triggers table data loading) to your `TableFooterPanel` component and call it when `onClick` event happens.

Comment: Pretty good answer, I would like to add that you might want to look into react context as well, as you can use to manage state at a much higher level.

Answer (score 2):

I would introduce a component to hold both the table and the footer, and put the state in this component. Then you pass a function as a prop down to the footer component, which will update the table data. Then you pass the table data as props to the table component.

```
function Customers({initialData = []}) {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState(initialData);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Customers</h1>
      <CustomerTable customers={customers} />
      <TableFooter addCustomer={(customer) => setCustomers([...customers, customer])} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

By setting initialData to default to an empty array, you can rely on array methods like .map in the table component.