# How to set data in child component dynamically by using props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-component

I have solved one of my problem in [this question for passing function as param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870322/how-to-trigger-a-function-of-sibling-component-in-react/71870496#71870496)

Now I am sending request to backend to add new record to db and I want to update the table immediately after adding new record by getting all items from backend.

Here is my parent App.js class having 2 component as **MainPanel** and **TableFooterPanel**:

```
function App() {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPostList = async () => {
      const response = await service.getCustomerList();
      setCustomers(response.data);
    };
    fetchPostList()
  }, []);

  const refreshTableData = () => {
    const fetchPostList = async () => {
      const response = await service.getCustomerList();
      setCustomers(response.data);
    };
    fetchPostList()
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Customer List</h1>
      <MainPanel param={customers}/>
      <TableFooterPanel funcParam={refreshTableData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am passing refresh function to TableFooterPanel which has a button to add new record and this function is triggered when a new record is added. Here is **TableFooterPanel**

```
function TableFooterPanel(props) {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const addNewCustomer = (name, surname) => {
        service.addCustomer(name, surname);
        props.funcParam();
    }

    return (

        <>
            <Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={firstName} onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" defaultValue={lastName} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>
                    <Button onClick={() => addNewCustomer(firstName, lastName)}>Add</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>

        </>

    );

}
export default TableFooterPanel;
```

And I want to refresh table data which lies in **MainPanel**:

```
function MainPanel(props) {

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  
  const deleteCustomer = (id) => {
    service.deleteCustomerById(id);
  }

  return (
    <ReactBootStrap.Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.param &&
            props.param.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.firstName}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td><Button onClick={() => deleteCustomer(item.id)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashRestore} /></Button></td>
              </tr>   
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </ReactBootStrap.Table>
  );
}
```

What happens here is when I add a new record, the table data is not changing dynamically, but if I add second data then I sees the previous data and updating table but still not showing the last added data. How can I refresh data and send latest data to **MainPanel**?

```
export default MainPanel;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this section:

```
const addNewCustomer = (name, surname) => {
  service.addCustomer(name, surname);
  props.funcParam();
}
```

It looks like you are calling the refresh function (`props.funcParam()`) before the `addCustomer` service is finished being called (since this is a `Promise`). That is causing your fetch to start fetching the existing data BEFORE it is updated.

You'll need to make the function asynchronous and then `await` it like this:

```
const addNewCustomer = async (name, surname) => {
  await service.addCustomer(name, surname);
  props.funcParam();
}
```

Now your function will wait for `service.addCustomer` to finish executing before executing the refresh fuction.

Comment: thanks man it worked nice. But when I want to do same for delete record (I send the same function to the MainPanel just like the other one), the props method is called but again same problem data is not refreshed. Why it is not working for delete ?

Comment: Are you making the function `async` and then `await`ing the call before calling the refresh function?

Comment: yes..  const deleteCustomer = async (id) => {
    await service.deleteCustomerById(id);
    props.funcParam();
  }

Comment: If you go look at `service.deleteCustomerById` and compare that to your other service functions is it also setup as a Promise?

Comment: they are both async only difference is delete is void method instead of returning something export async function getCustomerList() {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/customer/list");
}

export async function deleteCustomerById(id) {
    void axios.delete("http://localhost:8080/customer/" + id)
}

Comment: in my code I realized that, listing is working before delete. So when I call delete it is first refreshing data then calling  await service.deleteCustomerById(id);

Comment: Ah right, good job :) Guess you know how to solve it now then right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **service.addCustomer(name, surname)** is an async call and it posts data to server. Then you need to put **addNewCustomer** method into an async and await for the response of this call, once you get the response, you need to call **props.funcParam()** to get the latest data from server.